# Should NSString be nonatomic or atomic by default?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, automatic-ref-counting

What's the best practice for atomicity of NSString? I have seen bug that creeps up when NSString is set to use nonatomic, but I don't remember in what situation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/589392/420594

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between the atomic and nonatomic attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/whats-the-difference-between-the-atomic-and-nonatomic-attributes)

Comment: It's not atomicity so much as identity you have to be worried about with value objects (i.e. using copy instead of retain or strong).  Nonatomic properties only mess up reads during simultaneous writes.

Comment: Not a duplicate - I am asking for NSString specifically.  I know the difference between the two!